# how to make Ul clickable without Javascript

Tags: html, css

I have a code

```
<ul class="catven">

                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://" style="color:skyblue;text-decoration:none;margin-left:10px;">Abhijit Brew Tech Pvt Ltd</a></li>
                    <li><img src="http://localhost:8000" alt="" class="main-cat-img"></li>
                                    </ul>
```

So this code has a Link and an image i want the whole Ul to be clickable

Thanks,

Comment: What do you want to do when  ul is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the entire UL inside an anchor Tag but for that you will have to remove the `<a>` tag inside which is there in your `<li>`

You cannot put another `<a>` tag inside an `<a>` tag, It will close all the `<a>`tags when it finds first `</a>`

for eg:

```
<a href="www.google.com">
This is before a tag of li closes
<ul class="catven">

    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://" style="color:skyblue;text-decoration:none;margin-left:10px;">Abhijit Brew Tech Pvt Ltd</a></li>

    <li><img src="http://localhost:8000" alt="" class="main-cat-img"></li>
</ul>
This is after a tag of li closes
</a>
```

This will make only he first `<li>` or anything thats written between first `<a>` of google.com and end of `</li>` clickable

like below:

[image]

In order to make it work you will have to remove the inside the `<a>` tag

```
<a href="www.google.com">
This is before a tag of li closes
<ul class="catven">

    <li>Abhijit Brew Tech Pvt Ltd</li>

    <li><img src="http://localhost:8000" alt="" class="main-cat-img"></li>
</ul>
This is after a tag of li closes
</a>
```

like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

simply do add anchor tag out side the UL
like this :->

```
<a href="#"><ul class="catven">
<li><a target="_blank" href="http://" style="color:skyblue;text-decoration:none;margin-left:10px;">Abhijit Brew Tech Pvt Ltd</a></li>
<li><img src="http://localhost:8000" alt="" class="main-cat-img"></li>
</ul>
</a>
```

Comment: This will not make second <li> clickable